# Python: Iterate alphabetically over OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-2.7, ordereddictionary

In a script I have an OrderedDict `groups` that gets fed key/value pairs alphabetically.

In another part of the script, I'm checking against files that have the same same as `key`  like so:

```
for (key, value) in groups.items():        
    file = open(key, 'r') 
    # do stuff
```

Stuff happens just fine, part of which is printing a status line for each file, but how can I get Python to iterate through `groups` alphabetically, or at least numerically as they are ordered (since they are being entered in alphabetical order anyways)?

Comment: How are you adding the key/value pairs?

Comment: Do you need them to be in a dictionary at all?  Would key/value pairs in a tuple or list be sufficient?  You could then generate an OrderedDict as necessary out of the linear structure of key/value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of an `OrderedDict` is that you can iterate through it normally in the order that keys were entered:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> d[1] = 2
>>> d[0] = 3
>>> d[9] = 2
>>> for k, v in d.items():
        print(k, v)


(1, 2)
(0, 3)
(9, 2)
```

Just make sure you don't feed `OrderedDict(...)` a dictionary to initialize it or it starts off unordered.

Comment: I would say so then because I am still seeing it iterate through seemingly randomly. For instace, I have keys by the names of `movies` `blu-ray` and `hdtv`, however whenever I run the above, the output order is never in order of how they were entered.

Comment: @TurboTurtle Are you feeding it a dictionary? Which data structure does it begin with? Also can you show an example please

Comment: Ah!

I feel silly now, I was in fact feeding it a dictionary still. I thought I had changed that functionality but apparently I overlooked that.

Comment: @TurboTurtle: In that case you should delete your question, or at the very least update it so no one else wastes time on it.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is iterate through a dictionary in order of the keys, you can use a regular dictionary and `sorted()`:

```
>>> d = dict(s=5,g=4,a=6,j=10)
>>> d
{'g': 4, 's': 5, 'j': 10, 'a': 6}
>>> for k in sorted(d):
        print(k, ':', d[k])


a : 6
g : 4
j : 10
s : 5
>>>
```

(pardon the python3 `print()`)

If you really want to stick with the ordered dict, then read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) which shows an example of reordering an `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> # regular unsorted dictionary
>>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}

>>> # dictionary sorted by key
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
```

If you *really* entered them into an `OrderedDict` alphabetically in the first place, then I'm not sure why you're having trouble.

Comment: `sorted(d)` is better than `sorted(d.keys())`

Comment: Ahh.. Cool, I didn't even realize that!